# Usin' Me (Riley riddle)

Tags: riddle, word

It’s been a while since I’ve made a Riley, so here’s one:

> With my prefix you get the president, chairman, pope,
>
> Take away the infix’s end, or you’d easily be fooled.
>
> In the suffix I was mostly provided,
>
> And you are using me right now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is

> **electricity**
>  
>  Prefix: We **elect** a president, chairman, pope.
>  
>  Infix: I might be fooled by a **tric(k)**.
>  
>  Suffix: A self-reference to *electricity* being provided mostly in the
>  **city**.

Comment: Nice job Weather Vane!